# Error in permutations routine

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple class of object called ColourString.

I am trying to set up a recursive permutations routine to work with my jagged arrays of my class.

```
    static ColourString[][] perm2(int a, ColourString[][] x)
    {
        ColourString[][] retval = new ColourString[0][];
        foreach (ColourString[] p in x[a])
        {
            foreach (ColourString[] p2 in perm2(a + 1, x))
            {
                // do some stuff here to compare the strings in the colourString[] objects
            }
         }
         return retval;
     }
```

My code gives me the following error:

> Error 1 Cannot convert type 'Test.Form1.ColourString' to
>   'Test.Form1.ColourString[]'.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: The types don't match in the line of the error.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is there is a difference between `string` and `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

`x[a]` is a `ColourString[]`, so `p` in your `foreach` should be a `ColourString` not a `ColourString[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Other comments have already identified the problem, but allow me to be specific...

According to your function prototype, x is type ColourString[][]
Therefore x[a] is type ColourString[]
Your outer loop tries to iterate over objects of type ColourString[] belonging to an enumerable of type ColourString[], which is impossible.  The elements of x[a] would be ColourString, not ColourString[].

Comment: So, I have four arrays of type colourString[][]. What's the best way to structure looping through them to work out my perms? I've been banging my head against this for too long. Thank you.